# How to migrate tf data types such as Quaternion, Vector3, Transform to tf2?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, tf2-ros, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not much mentioned about tf2 datatypes on tf2_ros documentation at http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/.
While comparing to http://docs.ros.org/latest/api/tf/html/c++/, we don't have any data types mentioned. My C++ code has plenty of tf datatypes such as

```
 tf::Quaternion q(msg->pose[index].orientation.x,
                msg->pose[index].orientation.y,
                msg->pose[index].orientation.z,
                msg->pose[index].orientation.w);


 tf::Transform transform;
```

How will I migrate them to tf2_ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294936/how-to-migrate-tf-data-types-such-as-quaternion,-vector3,-transform-to-tf2?/) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2018-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the [Supported Datatypes](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2#Supported_Datatypes) section of the tf2 wiki.

The tf::Quaternion is a fork of the Bullet btQuaternion which will be your easiest conversion.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1